# Why did Truss's planned removal of a tax increase cause the market/pound to tank?

Tags: united-kingdom, economy

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this one. Why was it that when a tax break (or, removal of a tax increase) was announced, the market and pound reacted negatively? Wouldn't the market prefer lower cost of doing business?

Comment: Is this a political question or rather one for Economics?

Comment: @gerrit The planned tax cut was top of the agenda of when Liz Truss was campaigning for the Tory leadership contest, but this question is more economical even though both is entangled. The question might get more insightful answers at https://economics.stackexchange.com/ although the reaction of Liz Truss to the market reactions to her initial idea are again a political topic (and have been [asked about here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/76158/why-was-kwasi-kwarteng-sacked-and-jeremy-hunt-appointed-as-the-uk-finance-minist)).

Comment: Did they canceled that? https://www.npr.org/2022/10/14/1129013714/liz-truss-fires-treasury-chief Otherwise please add a link that explain what is “Truss's planned removal” for users that don't follow the news from UK.

Comment: Take care that there are no **fixed known answers** to trading questions about "why" a certain market moves one way or the other.  Different traders will have different ideas on "why" an index, stock, or commodity moved a certain way.

Comment: Or to say it another way: if we would know exactly why the markets move a certain way, we wouldn't need any banker or finance guru and we could always avoid any negative fallout. Just never do anything that "the markets" won't like. Simple as that.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The problem with the mini-budget was that it included large tax cuts, but with no corresponding cuts in spending, or increases in other forms of revenue.  This implied that government borrowing would have to substantially increase.  None of that appeared to have been planned nor discussed with anyone else, including the [Office for Budget Responsibility](https://obr.uk/).

The "markets" here aren't the individuals or companies who stood to gain the most.  It's the financial markets who buy and sell currencies, shares and commodities.

Sudden unplanned borrowing by a government results in rising interest rates, which further increases the cost of that borrowing.  The markets consider such an economy to be a high risk.

Comment: Although one has to say that the US for example sit on more than 30 trillion of debt and interest rates have been really low so far. There might be more at play.

Comment: @Trilarion: Said country also happens to print the world's predominant reserve currency, simultaneously the world's predominant trading currency. If you wish UK or some other country to be able to print currency with the same impunity, make sure the world replace US dollar with their currency first and the country of your choice too can do the same thing.

Comment: @Trilarion It's coming. If interest rates reach 13% (they won't) the US government will spend 100% of its tax revenue as interest on debt, and that will be the start of an unstoppable snowball effect. And that's if the US government doesn't spend anything at all (it does). To recover from that the government would have to shut down everything *and* raise taxes.

Comment: @user253751 That's why I wrote "so far". Nobody knows what will happen in the future, but we can judge the past. Historically, deficit spending was a really great idea for many countries. Why the markets were now so upset... maybe they have learned something.

Comment: @Trilarion The issue is not the amount of debt - it is the change in debt and the change in cost of funding the debt. Small or consistent changes are OK - jumps worry the markets

Comment: @mmmmmm Markets should ideally take all information into account. Not only the change in a quantity but also the absolute amount. But in this case nothing really happened, there was a plan which got cancelled. Still markets aren't back where they were before. Maybe there is some hysteresis in the markets, maybe there is just some panic below the surface. After all nobody knows what even the near future brings. Under different circumstances the markets might have looked much more favorably upon Liz Truss's plan.

Comment: @Trilarion "Why the markets were now upset" - this probably has something to do with what the government plans to spend the borrowed money on. I don't think investors are generally convinced that Truss's tax cuts will create as much economic growth as Truss claims they will, so the reaction is probably more negative than it would have been if she were borrowing to spend on something more effective.

Comment: @Trilarion Now everyone *knows* that the UK prime minister is the type of person who's going to increase government borrowing for no good reason. Which is not a good type of person (from a financial view) to have as prime minister.

Comment: @user253751 How is that different from all the previous PMs? Don't misunderstand me, I'm not a fan of tax cuts for the rich. But I think people are blaming Liz Truss as a person but I think that misses a point. Under somewhat different circumstances this really might have gone through. She wouldn't be the first to lower the burden on the well-off while saying that this basically pays for itself.

Comment: A simpler summary of this is that it was pretty clearly a desperation move to placate an upset demographic, and as such failed to reassure concerns by the markets that the change in government might result in clueless people in power making rash decisions with no grasp of the consequences.

Comment: Can you explain in simple terms why "Sudden unplanned borrowing by a government results in rising interest rates"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha supply/demand curve. If you borrow only a little, you borrow from the cheapest lender. If you borrow a lot, you max out the amount that person will lend you, and you have to go to the more expensive lenders. The actual implementation of this is an auction process.

Comment: @user253751 I see. Thank you for the explanation. But to be clear, are we talking about rising interest rates for government borrowing, or for everyone?

Comment: @FaheemMitha government borrowing, but most interest rates are based on the government borrowing rate plus a risk premium. Maybe a mortgage lender demands 2% extra because you might not pay your mortgage. If the government borrows at 1% they'd rather sell you a mortgage at 3.1%. If it's 1.5% the mortgage has to be 3.6% or else they'd rather lend their money to the government.

Comment: @user253751 Ah, I see. Interesting. So if the govt is doing a lot of borrowing, it makes the interest rate rise for everyone. Understood.

Answer (score 15):

There is yet another problem wrt government debt/bonds: **inflation**.

Basically, while the overall situation has been addressed on other answers in terms of debt and viability expectations, one also needs to remember that the UK, like many other countries, is facing extremely high inflation.

Truss's tax cuts were seen by some as **inflationary** (injecting more money into an inflationary economy).

Thus it was also widely expected the Bank of England would move in the *opposite direction* and increase interest rates.

[(Sept 22) Liz Truss’s selective Reaganomics won’t work | The Economist](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/09/22/liz-trusss-selective-reaganomics-wont-work)

> Liz Truss, Britain’s new prime minister, is now implementing Reaganomics in Britain, again creating dissonance in economic policy. **The Bank of England (boe) is fighting annual inflation of 9.9%. On September 22nd the bank raised interest rates by 0.5 percentage points. Yet the next day Ms Truss’s government was scheduled to lay out details of an enormous fiscal stimulus,** comprising tax cuts worth perhaps £30bn ($34bn) per year (1.2% of gdp) and subsidies for energy bills whose total cost across two years could reach £150bn.
>
> **The fuel that fiscal stimulus will inject into the economy will almost certainly lead the boe to raise interest rates faster than it otherwise would** (despite the fact that price caps on energy will bring down measured inflation).

One thing to remember there is that [bonds are less attractive as interest rates go up and that affects their prices and rates](https://www.im.natixis.com/us/portfolio-construction/bond-basics-interest-rates-and-yields).  Which gets people to ask more to finance debt via bonds and lowers the prices of existing bonds.  See also [Investopedia:  How Are Bond Yields Affected by Monetary Policy?](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/061715/how-bond-yield-affected-monetary-policy.asp) .

**i.e. "These bonds are gonna stink down the line, so I am less interested in holding them (lower price) or you have to pay me more (higher rates)!"**

It probably didn't help that Truss had also been [musing about bringing central bankers under more control](https://www.cnbc.com/2022/08/31/liz-truss-wants-to-review-the-bank-of-englands-mandate.html).  And, well, inflation **is** a problem and Truss was going to make it worse.

Comment: Where did you get "interest rates and bond yields are inversely related"? The link you provide certainly does not say so. (And should not.) Aside, since you are doing research on the topic, I suggest digging into from who and what warnings Truss received during leadership debate and such re her budget ideas. They should articulate the reasons a bit more than just market price actions.

Comment: @Argyll I think it meant interest rates and bond prices are inversely related.

Comment: [Investopedia:  How Are Bond Yields Affected by Monetary Policy?](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/061715/how-bond-yield-affected-monetary-policy.asp)  Bonds are less attractive as interest rates go up and that affects their prices and rates.  Rephrasing to avoid confusion and terminology debates.  I'll skip the leaders debate, thank you very much.  My answer here was to point out that other answers neglected the, very predictable, inflation aspect of Truss's mess.

Answer (score 6):

Tax cuts aren't always positive. Sometimes they are, sometimes they aren't. It always depends on the circumstances. In this case, the markets must have thought that the effective result is more negative than positive and gave corresponding feedback. Why could that have been?

A tax cut has always two implications. Some people have more money left but the government can also afford less or must borrow more. More borrowing increases borrowing costs but the additional factor here is the outlook of the economical development. Is a tax cut accompanied by tightened finances more likely to lead to growth (also in the long term) or less? If you believe that every functional government needs at least some funds, then there clearly exist an optimal tax rate with tax cuts beyond being poison for the economy. Many people even believe that during times of crisis like this one, governments should spend more not less, which would require adequate funding.

Markets might have gotten doubt about the long term ability to fulfill all its obligations including debt services of the British government. And indeed the debt to GDP ratio of Britain is relatively high.

But I wouldn't exclude that it was just financial speculation. After all a higher bond rate of UK government bonds is great for bond holders. They might just have seized the opportunity. After all, another PM, Margaret Thatcher, very successfully cut taxes in the past (albeit under quite different circumstances). Therefore it's not clear why the market reaction this time had to be that strong and that lasting (after all the plans have been reversed, but the bond rate hasn't gone down that much again).

Comment: In this instance, I don't think we need to guess or speculate; as Simon B's answer states, there are specific reasons (see, for example, [this article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/63229204)).

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Already commented on Simon B's answer. And in your article experts say that it was the last straw that broke the camel's back suggesting there are more issues at play. In more peaceful times maybe the tax cut would have gone through. Or if presented better (with a full business forecast).

Comment: A higher bond rate for new bonds is great for the buyers of those _new_ bonds. It's terrible for the holders of the _existing_ bonds. This explains the problems faced by British pension funds.

Comment: @MSalters Except that the higher rate reflects the higher risk of default?

Comment: @gerrit: For new bonds, the higher risk is indeed reflected in a higher rate. For existing bonds, the risk also went up, as did the _effective_ rate. That just means that the bond prices on the open market went _down_. A £1000 bond (nominal) might have dropped a few £, depending on the remaining duration on that bond. If the £1000 is to be repaid  next month, that will almost certainly still happen on time. But a 2% £1000 bond due in 2026? That won't be worth £1000 today.

Comment: @MSalters "the risk also went up" The risk might have gone up with the implementation of the planned tax cut. But since the mini budget never was realized, the reaction of the markets was a bit premature, kind of. It might even become a self-fulfilling prophecy. Higher bond rates surely do increase risks of default calling for even higher bond rates and so on.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  The article mentioned in the first comment is ... an article. (Note too, FWIW, the "article" mentioned is written by .. someone who writes articles.  Let's say the "article" was written by a trader, specifically, say we (somehow) dug up the human being who is the biggest trader, the highest volume, in the commodity in question. Say that person, the world's biggest trader in the commodity in question, wrote an "article" giving his opinion on why all the other traders did X. That might be interesting, but hardly definitive.)

Answer (score 6):

This is a very good question, although perhaps not quite for the reason that you think. To be clear, what we want to be able to explain is why the Truss-Kwarteng fiscal event resulted in *both*,

1. A fall in the price of the Pound, relative to other currencies.

*and*

2. A decrease in the market price (i.e. increase in yield) of UK government bonds (gilts).

Let's first consider the fiscal policy announcements made by the British government on September 23rd. You can see a detailed breakdown [here](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1105985/HMT_Autumn_Statement_2022_PRINT.pdf), but the two main points were:

- Approximately £60bn of subsidies for household and business energy bills over the next 6 months.
- Tax cuts costing about £45bn through to the end of the 2023 financial year. This is mostly made up of reduction in taxes on income and corporate profits.

The energy subsidies had already been announced, so are unlikely to have been a factor in the market reaction, but the tax cuts were new (although some had been promised by Truss during her party leadership campaign) and so it is reasonable to infer that they motivated the markets' behaviour.

Orthodox economics says that tax cuts will increase the aggregate demand in the economy. This in turn will result in demand-pull inflationary pressure. As the UK has an independent central bank, with a primary mandate to manage inflation, this inflationary pressure is likely to cause a rise in the official bank rate and a corresponding rise in the interest rate of other financial instruments, such as gilts. Since the coupon on existing gilts is (in most cases) fixed, the market price of those gilts will fall, bringing their yield back in line with the new, higher, interest rates. We can therefore understand the second of the two market reactions described above. What about the fall in the Pound?

In this case, conventional wisdom isn't so helpful. The traditional expectation is that an increase in interest rates in a country will cause the price of that country's currency to *increase*, since financial instruments denominated in that currency become more attractive to investors. However, here the opposite happened. This is quite unusual, but not unique. As [Paul Krugman points out](https://markets.businessinsider.com/news/currencies/uk-liz-truss-tax-cuts-markets-inflation-stagflation-paul-krugman-2022-9?utm_medium=ingest&utm_source=markets), this is the sort of behavior that one might expect to see exhibited by a developing, rather than advanced, economy. The argument put forward by Krugman, and many others, is that the attractiveness of the Pound due to anticipated interest rate rises has been more than offset by market fear over the UK government's lack of fiscal credibility. This has been described as the "moron risk premium".

In summary, the currency and gilt market movements can be understood as having two components:

1. Response to anticipated increase in short term UK interest rates, which causes the Pound to appreciate and gilts to depreciate.
2. Lack of confidence in the British government, which investors perceive as their shouldering increased risk and so causes the Pound to depreciate and gilts to depreciate.

If the magnitude of the second effect is greater than the first, then the observed market movements can be understood.

You might, not unreasonably, object that we still haven't *really* understood the market movements. What exactly *is* this risk premium or, to put it another way, what future event are markets concerned about? Simon Wren-Lewis has written an interesting piece on this [here](https://mainlymacro.blogspot.com/2022/10/why-it-is-crucial-to-understand-why.html) (the most relevant part is the appendix). His argument is that the big problem with the Truss-Kwarteng fiscal event was that it included *unfunded* tax cuts. An important point here is that unfunded doesn't just mean unmatched by spending cuts, governments can and do fund new expenditure with borrowing, but on this occasion the government simply didn't say how it was going to pay for the tax cuts at all. Indeed, it even prevented the Office for Budget responsibility from offering their assessment of the proposals, which probably exacerbated the issues even further. As Wren-Lewis explains, the presence of an unfunded commitment in the proposals meant that markets were left guessing how the treasury was going to make up the shortfall. Given the (then) chancellor's track record, a reasonable guess was that this was going to be achieved with spending cuts, which would themselves have *decreased* aggregate demand. In fact, given the nature of the tax cuts, and the likely spending cuts, it is quite plausible that the net effect would have been to *decrease* aggregate demand, which would also have resulted in lower interest rates. Markets were therefore faced with a wide range of possible medium term UK interest rates. This is what is meant by a "risk premium". Faced with this uncertainty, market participants naturally chose to reduce their exposure to assets denominated in Pounds, especially gilts, leading to a deprecation in both gilts and the price of the Pound.

As an epilogue, note that while the price of the Pound has largely recovered from its fall following the fiscal event, the same is not true of gilts and the British government, as well as British borrowers more generally, are still faced with higher borrowing costs.

Comment: The last paragraph is especially important in the light that the announced unfunded tax cuts have been abandoned in the meantime, the chancellor has been exchanged and a proper budget without these cuts has been promised. Nothing really happened but the negative impact still persists and wasn't even only temporary. Maybe "moron risk premium" means that once markets have decided you're a moron they'll make you pay more no matter what follows.

Comment: everyone was saying the BoE had to intervene to stop pension funds going bankrupt. why would a fall in the value of bonds held by pension funds cause those funds to go literally bankrupt rather than just decrease in value a little?  did they buy the bonds on margin or something?

Comment: @Timkinsella Yes, it appears that institutional investors, mostly pension funds, were facing a margin call and the BoE intervened to prevent a catastrophic collapse in gilt prices. Whether or not this constitutes "fiscal dominance" is a matter of debate.

Comment: buying bonds/gilts on margin is bizarre to me.  it seems like you'd be borrowing at the riskless rate of return to buy an asset that gives the riskless rate of return.

Comment: @Timkinsella I am far from an expert on pension funds, but my understanding is that they don't buy gilts on margin. They buy the gilts with cash paid into the fund, then borrow against the gilts to raise more cash with which to buy corporate bonds, which offer a better return. This seemingly bizarre arrangement is apparently motivated by regulatory requirements. When a margin call comes funds must sell their corporate bonds, which drives down bond prices in general or, even worse, sell the gilts they still hold (which are more liquid than corporate bonds).

Comment: @CharlieEvans regulatory requirements - in other words, the government forced pension funds to take relatively massive risks?

Comment: @user253751 Gilts are usually considered to be some of the lowest risk securities. Understandably, the government wanted pension funds to have low risk investment postures, but almost paradoxically this seems to have resulted in them using relatively risky financial instruments to make sure they could keep paying pensioners. The problem was particularly acute for defined benefit schemes, which need to pursue a liability-driven investment strategy. Perhaps the regulator would argue that this fiscal event could not reasonably be anticipated, and in any case, the BoE was able to save the day.

Answer (score -6):

Tax cuts for people who have the money to invest in companies and employ people tend to be a net plus for the economy.
Removing those tax cuts harms those peoples' power to employ people and invest in general, which harms the economy (increased unemployment, reduced productivity, reduced innovation, etc. etc.) and ultimately hurts the government by reducing tax income as well.
All of that ends up harming the currency, obviously.

Comment: The question is about why removing a tax **increase** caused a market/currency drop. Your answer is about why removing a tax **decrease** would cause a market drop. Not the same thing.

Comment: @Machavity what was actually removed by Truss was a tax DECREASE "for the rich".

Comment: @jwenting, removed _in response to the markets' activity this question is asking about_.

Comment: @Machavity a great number of people have been told (by the rich) that tax cuts for the rich are good for the economy. For some reason they fall for this so deeply they'll continue to believe it even in the presence of direct evidence to the contrary.